# How to allow trackwheel to scroll all direction?

Tags: blackberry, gridview

Here is my `navigationMovement()`:

```java
protected boolean navigationMovement(int dx, int dy, int status, int time) {

        int focusIndex = getFieldWithFocusIndex();

        while (dy > 0) {
            if (focusIndex >= getFieldCount()) {
                return false;
            } else {
                Field f = getField(focusIndex);
                if (f.isFocusable()) {
                    f.setFocus();
                    dy--;
                }
            }
        }

        while (dy < 0) {
            if (focusIndex < 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                Field f = getField(focusIndex);

                if (f.isFocusable()) {
                    f.setFocus();
                    dy++;
                }
            }
        }

        while (dx > 0) {
            focusIndex++;

            if (focusIndex >= getFieldCount()) {
                return false;
            } else {
                Field f = getField(focusIndex);

                if (f.isFocusable()) {
                    f.setFocus();
                    dx--;
                }
            }
        }

        while (dx < 0) {
            focusIndex--;

            if (focusIndex < 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                Field f = getField(focusIndex);

                if (f.isFocusable()) {
                    f.setFocus();
                    dx++;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
}
```

This only allows the track wheel to scroll left and right, but I want up, down, left and right.

my layout is [this](http://img805.imageshack.us/img805/8688/91334828.png).

It is a 3 rows x 4 columns.

This code is checking `getField(0->10)`, that's why it cannot from 0 to 4.

I want it to be movable in all directions. How to implement that?

**Updated**

```java
protected void sublayout(int width, int height) {
        int y = 0;

        Field[] fields = new Field[columnWidths.length];
        int currentColumn = 0;
        int rowHeight = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < getFieldCount(); i++) {
            fields[currentColumn] = getField(i);
            fields[currentColumn]
                    .setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener() {
                        public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
                            final int focusIndex = getFieldWithFocusIndex();
                            if (focusIndex == position) {
                                Main.getUiApplication().popScreen(
                                        mainscreen);
                            } else {
                                Main.getUiApplication().popScreen(
                                        mainscreen);
                                Main.getUiApplication().pushScreen(
                                        new Custom_LoadingScreen(1));
                                Main.getUiApplication().invokeLater(
                                        new Runnable() {
                                            public void run() {
                                                if (focusIndex == 0)
                                                    Main.getUiApplication()
                                                            .pushScreen(
                                                                    new Main_AllLatestNews());
                                                else
                                                    Main.getUiApplication()
                                                            .pushScreen(
                                                                    new Main_ParticularCategoryAllNews(
                                                                            catnewsid[focusIndex],
                                                                            focusIndex,
                                                                            cattitle[focusIndex]));
                                            }
                                        }, 1 * 1000, false);
                            }
                        }
                    });
            layoutChild(fields[currentColumn], columnWidths[currentColumn],
                    height - y);

            if (fields[currentColumn].getHeight() > rowHeight) {
                rowHeight = fields[currentColumn].getHeight() + 10;
            }

            currentColumn++;

            if ((currentColumn == columnWidths.length)
                    || (i == (getFieldCount() - 1))) {
                int x = 0;

                if (this.allRowHeight >= 0) {
                    rowHeight = this.allRowHeight;
                }

                for (int c = 0; c < currentColumn; c++) {
                    long fieldStyle = fields[c].getStyle();
                    int fieldXOffset = 0;
                    long fieldHalign = fieldStyle & Field.FIELD_HALIGN_MASK;

                    if (fieldHalign == Field.FIELD_RIGHT) {
                        fieldXOffset = columnWidths[c]
                                - fields[c].getWidth();
                    } else if (fieldHalign == Field.FIELD_HCENTER) {
                        fieldXOffset = (columnWidths[c] - fields[c]
                                .getWidth()) / 2;
                    }

                    int fieldYOffset = 0;
                    long fieldValign = fieldStyle & Field.FIELD_VALIGN_MASK;

                    if (fieldValign == Field.FIELD_BOTTOM) {
                        fieldYOffset = rowHeight - fields[c].getHeight();
                    } else if (fieldValign == Field.FIELD_VCENTER) {
                        fieldYOffset = (rowHeight - fields[c].getHeight()) / 2;
                    }

                    setPositionChild(fields[c], x + fieldXOffset, y
                            + fieldYOffset);
                    x += columnWidths[c];
                }

                currentColumn = 0;
                y += rowHeight;
            }

            if (y >= height) {
                break;
            }
        }

        int totalWidth = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < columnWidths.length; i++) {
            totalWidth += columnWidths[i];
        }

        if (position > -1) {
            Field f = getField(position);
            f.setFocus();
        }

        setExtent(totalWidth, Math.min(y, height));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just find the solution which is each move +/- column size

```
while (dy > 0) {
            if (focusIndex + columnwidth.length >= getFieldCount()) {
                return false;
            } else {
                Field f = getField(focusIndex + columnwidth.length);
                if (f.isFocusable()) {
                    f.setFocus();
                    dy--;
                }
            }
        }

while (dy < 0) {
            if (focusIndex - columnwidth.length < 0) {
                return false;
            } else {
                Field f = getField(focusIndex - columnwidth.length);

                if (f.isFocusable()) {
                    f.setFocus();
                    dy++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code that you treat dx and dy in the same way. You need to calculate next previous index differently depends on if it's horizontal scroll or vertical.

Btw, what manager do you use? `FlowFieldManager`? Because I think it's should work as expected in default `navigationMovement` implementation.

Comment: `public class Custom_GridField extends Manager`

Comment: Ok. So it's custom manager extended from Manager. Why not GridFieldManager http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/container/GridFieldManager.html

Comment: I copied from somewhere else.

Comment: Now the problem that source code writer did not make it can scroll up and down

Answer (score 0):

`navigationMovement` default will provide focus on all focusable components. 
It only matters what layout you have used & how did you arrange these managers. You have row, column wise structure, so if you used horizonal manager for a row, it's elements will get focus & after completing all elements, focus will be down to the second horizontal manager.

Comment: `public class Custom_GridField extends Manager`